# Evaluation of line integral

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, contour-integration

During one of the proofs in my complex analysis book, the author states the following argument:

$ \intop_{\varGamma_{M}}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz\underset{M\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $

Where $ \varGamma_{M} $ is half a circle with center at the origin (the half that is above the real axis).

I tried to evaluate it my self using $ |\intop_{\varGamma_{M}}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz|\leq\text{length}\left(\varGamma_{M}\right)\cdot\max_{z\in\varGamma_{M}}|\frac{e^{iz}}{z}| $

Since $ \text{length}\left(\varGamma_{M}\right)=M\pi $, and $ \max_{z\in\varGamma_{M}}|\frac{e^{iz}}{z}|=\max_{z\in\varGamma_{M}}|\frac{e^{i\left(\text{Re}\left(z\right)+i\text{Im}\left(z\right)\right)}}{z}|=\max_{z\in\varGamma_{M}}\frac{|e^{i\text{Re}\left(z\right)-\text{Im}\left(z\right)}|}{M}=\max_{z\in\varGamma_{M}}\frac{e^{\text{-Im}\left(z\right)}}{M}=\frac{1}{M} $

I cant see how $ \intop_{\varGamma_{M}}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz\underset{M\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $.

Where am I wrong?

The context:

The author trying to evaluate  $ \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx $ using the Residue theorem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer: ML inequality indeed does not work here, you need the Jacobi inequality.

Comment: @vitamind What is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\require{cancel}\Gamma_M(\theta)=Me^{2\pi i\theta}$ ($\theta\in\left[0,\frac12\right]$); the computations are similar if, say, $\Gamma_M(\theta)=Me^{i\theta}$ ($\theta\in[0,\pi]$). You have\begin{align}\left\lvert\int_{\Gamma_M}\frac{e^{iz}}z\,\mathrm dz\right\rvert&=\left\lvert\int_0^{1/2}\frac{e^{iMe^{2\pi i\theta}}}{\cancel{Me^{2\pi i\theta}}}2\pi i\cancel{Me^{2\pi i\theta}}\,\mathrm d\theta\right\rvert\\&=\left\lvert2\pi i\int_0^{1/2}e^{-M\sin(2\pi\theta)+iM\cos(2\pi\theta)}\,\mathrm d\theta\right\rvert\\&\leqslant2\pi\int_0^{1/2}\left\lvert e^{-M\sin(2\pi\theta)+iM\cos(2\pi\theta)}\right\rvert\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=2\pi\int_0^{1/2}e^{-M\sin(2\pi\theta)}\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=4\pi\int_0^{1/4}e^{-M\sin(2\pi\theta)}\,\mathrm d\theta\text{ (since $(\forall \theta\in[0,\pi]):\sin(\theta)=\sin(\pi-\theta)$)}\\&\leqslant4\pi\int_0^{1/4}e^{-4M\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta\text{ (since $(\forall\theta\in\left[0,1/4\right]):\sin(2\pi\theta)\geqslant4\theta$)}\\&=4\pi\left[\frac{e^{-4M\theta}}{-4M}\right]_{\theta=0}^{\theta=1/4}\\&=\pi\frac{1-e^{-M}}M.
\end{align}Now, use the fact that $\lim_{M\to\infty}\pi\frac{1-e^{-M}}M=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{iz}$ is not small near the two endpoints of the half circle, so it does not help to use max on the whole contour $\Gamma_M$.

But $e^{iz} = e^{-y}$ is small (very small) on most of the half circle.  You can use an integral (as in José's answer).  Or you could integrate separately: (1) on very small arcs near the end, and (2) on the rest of the half-circle where $e^{iz}$ is very small.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$ with $\epsilon < 1$.  Write
$$
\int_{\Gamma_M}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\;dz =
\left(\int_{\Gamma_1}+\int_{\Gamma_2}\right)\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\;dz
$$
where
$$
\Gamma_1 = \Gamma_M \cap \{\operatorname{Im} z \le s\}\\
\Gamma_2 = \Gamma_M \cap \{\operatorname{Im} z > s\}
$$
Here, $s$ is some small positive number **to be chosen later**.

Now
$\Gamma_1$ consists of two arcs of total length $2M\tan^{-1}(s/M)$.
The **first condition** in choosing $s$ is to make it so small that
$\tan^{-1}(s/M) < \epsilon/4$.  So
$$
\left|\int_{\Gamma_1}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\;dz\right|
\le \max_{\Gamma_1} \left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\right|\;\cdot\;\operatorname{length} \Gamma_1
\le \frac{1}{M}\cdot \frac{\epsilon M}{2} = \frac{\epsilon}{2}
\tag1$$

Next, $\Gamma_2$ has total length less than $\pi M$.
On $\Gamma_2$, we have
$$
\left|\frac{z^{iz}}{z}\right| = \frac{e^{-y}}{M} < \frac{e^{-s}}{M}
$$
The **second condition** in choosing $s$ is that $e^{-s} < \epsilon/(2\pi)$.
Compute
$$
\left|\int_{\Gamma_2}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\;dz\right|
\le \max_{\Gamma_2} \left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\right|\;\cdot\;\operatorname{length} \Gamma_2
\le \frac{\epsilon}{2 \pi M}\cdot \pi M = \frac{\epsilon}{2}
\tag2$$
If we do all this, then from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
$$
\left|\int_{\Gamma_M}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}\;dz\right| < \epsilon
$$

What is left is to show:  When $M$ is large enough, then we can choose $s$
so that
$$
\tan^{-1}\frac{s}{M} < \frac{\epsilon}{4}
\quad\text{and}\quad
e^{-s} \le \frac{\epsilon}{2\pi}
$$
That is
$$
s < M\tan\frac{\epsilon}{4}
\quad\text{and}\quad
s \ge \log\frac{2\pi}{\epsilon}
\tag3$$
For fixed $\epsilon \in (0,1)$,
$$
\lim_{M\to\infty} \left(M\tan\frac{\epsilon}{4} 
- \log\frac{2\pi}{\epsilon}\right) = +\infty
$$
and therefore, for $M$ large, we can choose $s$ to that $(3)$ holds.